# Exclude abandoned Code Review Response from My Work query

Tags: tfs, tfs-code-review

If a TFS Code Review was closed by the requester before the requestee(s) have a chance to respond, the Code Review Response item seems to be stuck in State=Requested, Assigned To = @Requestee.

If we have a work item query that is showing all work in the requestee's queue, the response for the abandoned code review should not appear. However, we do want to see Code Review Response items that are in State=Requested for Code Reviews that have not yet been closed.

Is there a way to modify my work item query to distinguish Code Review Response items between those that belong to active or closed Code Reviews? In both cases, their State=Requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot change the sate, it's by design. However you can use the type of query : `Work items and direct links` to distinguish Code Review Response which the State=Requested:

- Query the `Code Review Response` items that belong to **Closed** Code
  Reviews :

[image]

- Query the `Code Review Response` items that belong to **Active**
  (***Un-closed***) Code Reviews :

[image]